# Effect of broswer breakpoint on rendering

Tags: javascript, html, browser, callstack

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    <h1 id="hello"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
const h1 = document.getElementById('hello');

h1.innerText='Hello'

console.log("hello")
```

I ran a live server to serve index.html on edge browser. and a put a breakpoint using browser developer tool on the last line of the index.js file which is `console.log("hello")`. I thought the dom manipulation done by the index.js is not yet rendered because this javascript file's execution context is occupying the call stack. But the browser window has the **Hello** text printed on it when breakpoint pauses the execution of the javascript code.

[image]
Why did this happen?